# Controll the application that opens the links

Tags: ubuntu, url, xdg-open

My scenario is simple - I have two browser profiles, personal and work. Now I have two sources I get urls.

My goal is to have a way to open urls from one source (let's say Slack) with personal profile and from another one (e.g. Teams) with work profile.
I already created proper entry in /usr/share/applications which runs script inside my bin dir and it works fine but ofc opens all links with the same profile.
I see three ways of solving that:

1. I heard somewhere in past that I can use shift-click/ctrl-click which could use different applications than just click, however cannot find any information what happens internally then and how to use that.
2. Use some global variable which I could change with some shortcut and use it in script that opens the browser. Probably could write it to some file with echo with script and run it with rofi, but not sure is it elegant.
3. Somehow tell the OS the context where I clicked the link - if it came from Slack use application A, if Teams use B.

I am using bspwm and sxhkd under X11.

Could you guide me a bit what directions would you go if you were me and provide details where should I dig further?

Comment: wherever "somewhere" is from your 1. question, that doesn't exist in general. Individual programs can have keybindings where "shift-click" means something different than "click", but it's not a desktop-wide thing.

Comment: Which browser do you use here?

Comment: @GillesQuénot qutebrowser, but it doesn't matter - I can run most browsers with any profile from terminal using proper command

Answer (score 2):

I don't know `qutebrowser`, but what you can do to know which profile you use with this browser wrapper:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

profileInUse=$(
    {
        lsof ~/.config/qutebrowser/*/* \
        ~/.mozilla/firefox/*/.parentlock \
        ~/.config/chromium/Profile*/Cookies 2>/dev/null
    } | grep -oPm1 '(qutebrowser|chromium|firefox)/[^/+]+'
)

case "$profileInUse" in
    qutebrowser/work*)
        qutebrowser --profile work "$@"
    ;;  
    qutebrowser/home*)
        qutebrowser --profile home "$@"
    ;;
    chromium/z*)
        chromium --user-data-dir=z "$@"
    ;;  
    firefox/x*)
        firefox -P x "$@"
    ;;
    *)
        echo >&2 "NOT implemented browser error ${profileInUse%/*}"
        exit 1
    ;; 
esac
```

Save this as `browser` in your path, then set your system to make it the default browser; E.x:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser browser.desktop
```

(You need to create a `browser.desktop` file).

Comment: Thanks for that snippet! It seems kinda tricky but it's not exactly what I need - the link I am clicking doesn't come from a browser, it can come from a slack or (recent case) from terminal after calling `aws sso login` (or even sometimes there are links in terminal which are opened after the click). And I can have opened multiple profiles/browsers at once which (if I understand corretly this snippet) would cause a problem.

Comment: Check my edited post

Comment: You are the best! One extra request, could you explain what exactly pfInUse is storing?

Comment: The name of the profile in use: `ProfileInUse`